# Why does Stan Lee play random extras in Marvel films?

Tags: cameo, stan-lee

While looking at the [cast](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0800080/fullcredits) of The Incredible Hulk I say Stan Lee was cast as:

> **"Milwaukee Man Drinking From Bottle"**

I've noticed he plays an extra in the Iron Man, X-Men, Spider Man films as well as other Marvel films.

Why does he cast himself as an extra in a lot of his films he's involved with producing? Is it just a bit of joke just to see do people notice him?

Comment: Because he can. Because he's old. Because he's rich. Because he's the creator of most of the characters. Because it's fun. Any or all of the above.

Comment: Also, everybody who watches these films knows who he is. Everyone notices him. He's a self-promoter.

Comment: Edited on a technicality as they aren't *his* movies.  I'm such a stickler for detail xD

Comment: Peter Jackson does something similar - just for fun.

Comment: Not to forget QT and his cameos!

Comment: There is a rumour that he is actually 'The Watcher'

Comment: He's denied it.

Comment: Because he grew up watching Alfred [Hitchcock](http://bloomsburyfilmandmedia.typepad.com/continuum_film_and_media/2012/10/hitchcocking-it-or-making-movies-about-movie-makers.html) movies?

Comment: I just think it's sad that they put so much effort trying to make sense about all sorts of details but that this guy always plays a different character. If a kid watched this he would never understand why this guy is not playing a coherent character in the universe of Marvel movies...

Comment: @fabriced Will somebody PLEASE think of the children! #Hysteria

Comment: @MicroMachine: “If a kid watched this he would never understand why this guy is not playing a coherent character in the universe of Marvel movies”. I think you underestimate kids, especially those who saw *[Rise of the Silver Surfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Four%3A_Rise_of_the_Silver_Surfer#Cast)* in 2007 and *[Captain America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America:_The_First_Avenger)* in 2011.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Stan Lee isn't casting himself in these cameos - it's a tradition which started back in 1989 with one of the original TV Hulk spin-off movies, one that has endured ever since.

[image]

From *The Trial of the Incredible Hulk* - 1989

He may have a producer credit on the Marvel movies, but his involvement doesn't go any deeper than just being a beloved figurehead - these cameos are homages by the filmmakers.

A comprehensive list of his cameo appearances, plus images, can be found [here](http://www.listal.com/list/stan-lees-marvel-movie-cameos).

Quoting Lee himself:

*"It’s almost scary ‘cause they just give me a date. They’ll say, "Stan, come over next Thursday for your cameo," but they don’t tell me what it is. So, I show up and they say, "Go to wardrobe." In wardrobe, they say, "We want to get you a white shirt and a green sweater and a black zippered jacket," and I’ll say, "Don’t bother, I’m wearing one." And then, they say, "But, you can’t wear yours!," and they look around and get me the exact same thing, but I’m not allowed to wear my own. And I still don’t know what my role will be. I go on the set and one minute before we’re gonna shoot, the director says, "Okay, Stan, this is what I want you to do. So, I don’t know what is expected of me, until I get there, but of course, I do it magnificently."*

Unconfirmed reports suggest that he will be a beauty contest Judge in Iron Man 3 and a London bus driver in Thor: The Dark World.

Comment: how dare you spoil the beauty contest scene in IM3, probably the most important scene of all!

Comment: BTW, that quote from Stan Lee is from [this interview](http://collider.com/stan-lee-cameo-the-avengers-iron-man-3/) _(where he is asked about his __Iron Man 3__ cameo)_

Comment: That psycho role was better then expected London bus driver.

Comment: *"but of course, I do it magnificently"* true as always

Answer (score 0):

Because he is a watcher or works for them. Likely Uatu, the watcher that's assigned to watch Earth. Confirmed by Marvel in the Guardians of the Galaxy Vol 2.

> Marvel chief Kevin Feige has endorsed the popular fan theory that Stan Lee is playing the same character in all of his MCU roles. http://screenrant.com/stan-lee-mcu-cameo-theory-marvel-kevin-feige/
>
> > “Yes, we always thought it would be fun. Stan Lee clearly exists, you know, above and apart from the reality of all the films. So the notion that he could be sitting there on a cosmic pit stop during the jump gate sequence in Guardians was something very fun – James had that idea and we shot that cameo and loved it so much, you know, you see it a couple of times in the movie. It wasn’t in for a long time and we put it back in towards the end of the process where he references that time he was a Federal Express agent – we thought it would be fun to put that in there because that really says, so wait a minute, he’s this same character who’s popped up in all these films.”

Comment: This in-universe factoid is certainly an interesting tidbit, but seems more of an afterthought and not too related to why he was originally cast in all those roles. The answer seems much less related to this question here than to [that one](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/10374/49).