# Did Stan Lee make a cameo in The Wolverine?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, the-wolverine, stan-lee

I just got back from watching [The Wolverine](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1430132/combined), and I was too caught up in the story/battle sequences to notice if Stan Lee made an appearance.

Did anyone notice him whilst watching the movie? If so, which scene was he in?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, Stan lee only appears in the film versions of characters he created alone - he was not the sole creator of Wolverine.

This is also the reason why he does not have a cameo in Ghost Rider, Elektra or The Punisher.

This subject has approached before in a couple of SE questions [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10370/why-doesnt-stan-lee-make-a-cameo-appearance-in-x2) and [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10361/why-does-stan-lee-play-random-extras-in-marvel-films).

Comment: Apparently he would've if he could've, going by @kham 's answer.

Comment: http://comicbook.com/blog/2013/07/28/stan-lee-explains-lack-of-cameo-in-the-wolverine/  His role in creating characters has nothing to do with whether or not he cameos in their movies.

Comment: *"Stan lee only appears in the film versions of characters he created alone"* Then why was he in Deadpool, Big Hero 6, and Princess Diaries 2?

Answer (score 10):

[Stan Lee says](http://comicbook.com/blog/2013/07/28/stan-lee-explains-lack-of-cameo-in-the-wolverine/) he just didn't have time to fly to Australia to film the cameo.

Comment: I noticed that it was filmed in Australia. I wonder if Hugh wanted that badly.

Answer (score 5):

No, Stan Lee did not make an appearance in The Wolverine.

Comment: He is, however, credited as an Executive Producer.

Comment: It's Marvel! He always is!